noble 24.04 ssh after DHCP reservation
When I installed 24.04 on my two machines (let's call them foo1 and foo2), Ubuntu settings has an ssh feature in settings|system|secure shell which would allow me to simply type ssh foo2 from foo1 to access it (on the local network).
Since then, I got a shiny new mesh WiFi network and I did some tidying and reserving of IP addresses by reserving them in DHCP on my router.
All good.
Except that I cannot use ssh foo2 (or ssh foo1 from the other machine) anymore.
I get:
ssh foo2
ssh: Could not resolve hostname foo2: Temporary failure in name resolution

I assume that when I installed Ubuntu, the hostnames were tied to a local IP address somewhere, but I can't find it - how do I get that functionality back?
Edit: Actually, that cannot be correct can it, or it wouldn't work for non-reserved IP addresses. It must be by hostname, but why can it no longer resolve the hostname?
It's hardly temporary - It's been like it a week with me trying restarts, turning the ssh settings off and back on, etc.

Can you pull the full details of your network?  I ask this because there's two problems: (1) DNS has to exist, and (2) your search domain has to be set properly from DHCP options so hostname lookups attempt to use the local domain set by DHCP for your first DNS queries (which irequires your local network's DNS servers to be set to DHCP right).  Do other DNS lookups resolve properly?  Like google, the ubuntu repositories, etc.?

Which details would you like and how do I get them? I can ssh out to my VM in the cloud, I can ssh back into foo1 OR foo2 from my VM in cloud. I can ssh between foo1 and foo2 (both ways) by using my public IP address (and separate ports for foo1 and foo2).
